# Playlist Starting point and duration

Tags: video, html5-video, playlist, video-editing, m3u

I would like to create a script base playlist like m3u or pls format to play multiple video files at certain starting point and duration for each of them.

You can specify a start point for Youtube video link for example. Can I do the same for a playlist file?

Alternatively, can I do it using html script?

The idea is I don't want to cut and trim multiple files video files and create duplicates, then change my mind and change the starting point. With a script, this can be done easily with no video editing required.

Thanks